# How to fix SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The prefix "dt" for attribute "dt:dt" associated with an element type "CNDB" is not bound

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I found some files that generate error messages and now I would like to fix the errors. How do I fix the error below?

If I do

```
mediainfo --Output=XML 7483.MOV >data.xml
```

then I edit the file and remove a lot of lines that are not needed to produce the error, and then

```
java -jar /opt/local/share/java/saxon9he.jar data.xml test.xsl
```

I get the error:

```
Error on line 2 column 29 of data.xml:
SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The prefix "dt" for attribute "dt:dt" associated
with an element type "CNDB" is not bound.
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported
```

The test.xsl contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" exclude-result-prefixes="fmp date redirect"
    xmlns:saxon="http://icl.com/saxon"
    xmlns:date="http://www.jclark.com/xt/java/java.util.Date"
    xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect"
    xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
    xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="binary.base64"
    xmlns:xalan="org.apache.xalan.xslt.extension.redirect"
    extension-element-prefixes="saxon xalan redirect dt">
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The data.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CNDB dt:dt="binary.base64">Q00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00W
IUNNFiFDTRYhQ00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00WIUNNFiFDTRYhQ00W
IT1NFiE9TRYhPU0WIT1NFiE9TRYhPU0WIT1NFiE9TRYhPU0WIT1NFiE9TRYhPU0WIT1NFiE9TRYhPU0WIT1NFiE9TRYhPU0WIT1NFiE9TRYhPU0WIT1NFiE9</CNDB>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is very clear

> The prefix "dt" for attribute "dt:dt" associated with an element type "CNDB" is not bound.

Your input XML is not namespace-well-formed, because the `CNDB` element has an attribute named `dt:dt` but there is no `xmlns:dt="..."` on the `CNDB` or one of its ancestors.

Comment: Thanks, editing the xml through sed and removing dt: fixed the problem. So since the XML was generated by mediainfo, I guess I should report it to them?

Comment: @dontomaso yes, if they're generating bad XML then they need to fix it.

Comment: @dontomaso - You said "then I edit the file and remove a lot of lines that are not needed to produce the error"...are you sure you didn't remove the namespace declaration yourself?

Comment: @DanielHaley yes, the error was there before I started manually removing lines. I removed lines to see what caused the error and to reduce the data to post here at stackoverflow.

Comment: @dontomaso - Thanks for clarifying. Like Ian said, I'd definitely let mediainfo know.

Comment: Reported, but he will not fix it until someone who knows XML comes along and fixes it in the mediainfo code.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ian writes in his answer, this problem was caused by `mediainfo` generating invalid `XML`. The problem has been reported, but it seems the problem won't be fixed anytime soon due to a lack of developers with enough XML skill for fixing the problem.

My "solution" for now is to fix the output using `sed` as follows:

```
mediainfo --Output=XML 7483.MOV | sed -e 's#<CNDB dt:dt=#<CNDB dt=#g' >data.xml
```